# Least square problem and pre-Hilbert, Numerical analysis Homework

Tags: numerical-methods

[image: Homework problem]

3. how to show the minimizing max has a solution.
4. confusing about how to approve it

Comment: Welcome to math.SE: since you are new, I wanted to let you know a few things about the site. In order to get the best possible answers, it is helpful if you say in what context you encountered the problem, and what your thoughts on it are; this will prevent people from telling you things you already know, and help them give their answers at the right level.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hint to (4). By expanding we get
$$\|\alpha f+g\|^2\geq\|g\|^2\iff \alpha^2\|f\|^2+2\alpha\langle f,g\rangle\geq0.$$
Now if $\langle f,g\rangle=0$ we have $\|\alpha f+g\|\geq\|g\|$ for any real $\alpha$.

If now $\langle f,g\rangle\neq0$  show that for $\alpha=-\dfrac{\langle f,g\rangle}{\|f\|^2}$ that $\|\alpha f+g\|<\|g\|$.

Comment: Thanks a lot, do you have idea on 3?

Comment: Unfortunately not; I know a about Chebyshev's approximation in context of functional analysis only.